# Regroup Queryset by ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm working with django and I have to recover the records of a model called Restaurante, this has attributes such as Name, Address, Phone, City, etc. and also, it has a food_type attribute that is a ManyToManyFiel, with my model called FoodType, because in a restaurant you can serve many types of food (such as Mexican, Italian, vegan, etc.) and a type of food, it can be offered in many restaurants and I want to recover all the restaurants in X city and group them by types of food, in the following way:

1. Vegan Food

   - The compostera
   - Natural foods
   - GreenRestaurant
   - Resto Bar
2. Italian Food

   - Resto Bar
   - Piere Pizzas
   - The compostera
3. Mexican food

   - Jalisquitos
   - Maya Tacos
   - GreenRestaurant

I tried to do it with the tag {% regroup%}, but it shows me the expected output, I attach the code of the models:

```
class FoodType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length = 150,
        blank = False,
        null = False,
        help_text = 'Enter the name of the type of food',
        verbose_name = 'Name'
    )
    description = models.CharField (
        max_length = 250,
        blank = False,
        null = False,
        help_text = 'Enter a brief description of this type of food',
        verbose_name = 'Description'
    )

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField (
        max_length = 50,
        blank = False,
        null = False,
        help_text = 'Enter the name of the restaurant',
        verbose_name = 'Restaurant Name',
    )
    address = models.CharField (
        max_length = 200,
        blank = False,
        null = True,
        help_text = 'Enter the physical address of the restaurant',
        verbose_name = 'Addres'
    )
    telefono = PhoneNumberField(
        null = False,
        help_text = 'Enter the phone number of the restaurant in the format +999999999',
        unique = True,
        verbose_name = 'Phone Number'
    )
    city = models.ForeignKey(
        City,
        related_name = 'ubica_en',
        on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING,
        blank = False,
        null = True,
        help_text = 'Select the city to which this restaurant belongs',
        verbose_name = 'City',
    )
    administrator = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name = 'es_registrado_por',
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
        blank = False,
        null = False,
        help_text = 'User who added this restaurant',
        verbose_name = 'Who registered it?'
    )
    food_type = models.ManyToManyField(
        FoodType,
        help_text = 'Select the type (s) of food served in this restaurant',
        related_name = 'restaurants',
        verbose_name = 'Type of food',
        blank = False
    )
```

I attach the code with the tag {% regroup%}:

```
{% regroup restaurants by food_type as food_type_list %}
{% for food_type in food_type_list %}
  {{ food_type.grouper }}
  {% for restaurant in food_type.list %}
    <h1>{{ restaurant|upper }}</h1>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I hope you can help me in advance, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I solved it in the following way:

```
foods = FoodType.objects.all()
group = {}
for food in foods:
    restaurant_key = '_'.join([str(restaurant.pk) for restaurant in comida.restaurant_set.all()])
    if not restaurant_key in group and restaurant_key! = '':
        group[restaurant_key] = {'restaurants': food.restaurant_set.all(), 'foods': []}
    if restaurant_key! = '':
        group[restaurant_key]['foods'].append(food)
context ['group'] = group
```